# DynamoDb Large table query speed

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

we are moving from mysql to dynamo db
before that i have some questions

my mysql table has 40 million items on it

has a start i moved 225,000 to one table on dynamo db to test if it worth its

my object look like this:

```
"Partition key"{
             account_id:number,
             book_id:1,
             reader_id:2,
             field:3,
             field:4,
             ...
}
```

my first test is to fetch data by account_id

so i created
a global index for this field

what i tried:

**query** all the data where account_id = 2
using the correct index

it took something like 90 seconds
and 225,000 items has returned

is this normal speed for dynamo db ?

now lets say i dont need the actual objects to returned
i just need to count how much objects

matches:

account_id=3

AND book_id=10

AND reader_id=222

i know i need to **SCAN** the table for this

what will be the best approach 
and can i expect a "normal" speed for this kind of scan

for a 40 million items one table ?

thank a lot

Comment: you should never do a scan. rather use elastic search to do scan, and dynamo for put and get.

Comment: which choice do i have in this scenario?
i must use scan

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb scans are expensive and almost should never be used, but if your requirement is like this, you can take the following approach,

maintain two tables one what you have already created and another one where you store computed values,

you can use dynamodb streams, lambda function to populate data in second table,  this will make sure

1. atomicity of operation in the first table and
2. when you set concurrency to lesser number in lambda, it will solve the race condition in the second table.

Now whenever you want to compute data, you go to the second table and fetch the data. it will make sure you don't have to do a scan.

Pros of the approach

1. Will not have to do a scan.

Cons

1. will have to maintain 2 table.
2. if requirements changes we may have to repopulate the second table and will be a significant effort.(PS it can be made easier if you are using lambda and dynamo, First clean the second table. now you just change some random field in your first table's items and it will go through the pipeline, populating the second table.)
3. delay in availability of data.(since data population is async)

in the above suggested approach, 2 tables can be gotten away with, if you use a special secondary key for computed value in the first table only. but it will have issues like

1. your table schema may evolve and computed value may not have those values. (like defining a new secondary key?)(Hence suggesting to have 2 tables)
2. Race conditions will be there where two requests are simultaneously trying to update  the same records. (Hence the lambda function with less concurrency so that 
   2 threads don't work on same record.)
3. Atomicity: if the second write fails we may have to revert the first put.